# Value Accessor issues on a radio button component

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-controlvalueaccessor

So I'm trying to make just a really simple and clean radio button component that can be used with value accessor to be used in the common angular forms scenarios with `FormsModule`, `ReactiveFormsModule` and using `changeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` but I've ran into the issue(s) you can see **[ON THIS Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zoklkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradiobutton%2Fradiobutton.component.ts)** where I'm getting unexpected results which I understand is probably me missing something since it's been a long time since I've done a custom radio.

When it first loads, you get the radio outlines but no labels until you click something and `writeValue` and `onModelChange` are **undefined** while I get a  `No value accessor for form control with name:` error. So could use another pair of eyes so I can use the instance with good 'ol ngModel, formControlName, FormBuilder.

You'll see in the Stackblitz the value accessor is there and implementing `ControlValueAccessor` so I'm a bit confused since I've done the same approach with another component recently just fine. I could copy/paste parts of the blitz here but figured the example should be enough however if not just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made few changes to your code on [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eadkat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradiobutton%2Fradiobutton.component.ts), please check and let me know if it resolves your issue.

Below is the summary of the changes done:

- Introduced a new RadioButtonComponent property named `internalValue` and used it to bind to `[ngModel]`. Also updating it's value within `writeValue()` method.
- Commented the code within `writeValue` related to `this.checked` and manual update to `input` element's `checked` property. That should automatically be handled by Angular Forms API.
- Within RadioButtonComponent html template removed `[attr.checked]` binding and instead of using attribute binding for `name` and `value`, simply used property binding.
- In app.component.html instead of using property binding, used two-way binding `[(ngModel)]` syntax, so that the value gets reflected when you print it using `ngModel: {{testing}}`

You may change/tweak other things too, but hopefully the above changes will help you get going.

Comment: This definitely puts me back on track especially the checked changes thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
providers: [RADIO_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
```

You are missing this in your code. You need to add this in providers in component decortor

Comment: Ah yes I did forget that when I was making the quickie stackblitz, but after adding it you get the results I was describing wherein `ngModelChange` returns undefined as the event and an initial selection can't change nor update the `ngModel` but good catch thank you! I updated the SB accordingly.